# Android preferences, customize EditTextPreference

Tags: android, preferencescreen, android-settings, edittextpreference

I am setting up the `PreferenceScreen` for my Android application. 
I included a `EditTextPreference` to specify a remote server.
Now I want to provide the user with an option to reset the address to the initial value inside the popup:

Basically what I want is a third button, *"RESET"*  besides *"CANCEL"* and *"OK"*

[image]

I there any easy way to achieve this customization ?

Code for completness:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="General">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="http://stackoverflow.com/"
        android:dialogTitle="Specify the remote server: "
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:key="serverAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:summary="somesSummaryText"
        android:title="Server Address"
        android:persistent="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no way of doing so using the `EditTextPreference` but you can always have a simple `Preference` and add your AlertDialog in its OnClick with whatever customization you have in mind.

```
<Preference
    android:key="pref_key_edit"
    android:summary="@string/pref_summary_edit"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_edit"/>
```

and override `onPreferenceTreeClick` your `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment`

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
    switch (preference.getKey()) {
        case "pref_key_edit":
            // Do whatever you want here
            return true;
    }
    return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, despite there is no easy answer. It seems I have to read way more into it to get it working the way I want it to (I am very new to android). Thankfully you pushed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you can use a **Preference** in the **Preference Screen** for this. And on Preference's onPreferenceClickListener show your custom dialog and get value from the dialog and save them using **SharedPreference**.